# InvalidFormatException in Java POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

This is the exception I am getting:

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
```

The file I am trying to open is an .xls file, I searched for possible solutions, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142282/exception-using-poi) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992071/org-apache-poi-poixmlexception-org-apache-poi-openxml4j-exceptions-invalidforma), but I am already doing this correctly, so this is not the problem.

My code:

```
InputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
```

sheetNumber is an int (It´s always 0 in my software) and the path is correct, I tested these two many times before posting this, to make sure I am not failing there. The line that is throwing the exception is:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

(If you want more details on the code, you can find the whole class [Here](https://github.com/mayuso/Datuk/blob/master/src/main/java/excel/Excel.java))

Does anyone know where can I be failing? Thank you all.

Comment: If you try to open the file with Excel, can it open it? And if you save-as in Excel, does the new file work fine with POI?

Comment: I can open it without any problem (Ubuntu 14.04), and when I save it again from my PC (Overwrite it using "Save as...") my software throws no exception with the new file. (I must say I do not create the excels).

Comment: I am not sure what that means though. File extension is incorrect before overwriting it?

Comment: If you grab a copy of the [Apache Tika CLI App](http://tika.apache.org/download.html) and run that on the file with `--detect foo.xlsx` and `--detect < foo.xlsx`, what does it report for the two cases?

Comment: The first one (Without `<`) throws exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: foo.xlsx`. The second one (With `<`) tells me the file does not exist.

Comment: If I run the exact same two commands using `.xls` instead of `.xlsx`, it gives me `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet` in both cases.

Comment: A classmate has told me he can´t open these excel files in Windows 7 (MS Excel). I can with Ubuntu 14.04 (LibreOffice) though.

Comment: You need to replace `foo.xlsx` with the name of your problematic file!

Comment: Yes, I know, I did (I am dumb, but not so much xD), but my file is .xls (Not .xlsx), that´s why it says it does not exist, and that´s why I added the report when I run the command for `.xls`.

Comment: `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet` = Open Document Format = ODS. You need to use OpenOffice / LibreOffice or similar. From java, try Apache ODFToolkit. Apache POI can't handle these files

Comment: Thank you. In fact, this is really bad news, I need to learn about a new API now, without much time :(. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting some comments to an answer

Your first issue is the version of Apache POI you're using. If you were to use POI 3.15 beta 1 or newer, you'd get a much more helpful Exception in this situation.

In POI 3.15 beta 1 and newer, you'll get a [ODFNotOfficeXmlFileException](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/ODFNotOfficeXmlFileException.html) with a message like:

```
ODFNotOfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in ODF (Open Document) Format. Formats like these (eg ODS, ODP) are not supported, try Apache ODFToolkit
```

.

As it is, you can find (and have found, thanks!) out what your file really is by using [the Apache Tika CLI App](http://tika.apache.org/download.html) in `--detect` mode. As you found, that gave `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet` which is an OpenDocument Format Spreadsheet, normally with the `.ods` extension. So, someone has renamed the `.ods` file to `.xlsx`, which while it may make Excel open it, doesn't magically change the format!

Apache POI doesn't support the ODF formats, so you'll either need to convert the file to a true Excel format, or use something like [Apache ODF Toolkit](https://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/) to process it.

Comment: Yes, I am in fact using POI 3.13. Thank for your answer, time for me to start learning about ODF Toolkit.

Comment: Offtopic update: I told the one creating the excel files about all of this and he realised he was creating the excel files wrong. We fixed it, and Apache POI works fine now. However, I must say ODF Toolkit is interesting (I won´t quit learning about it xD), and the answer still 100% correct.